# How to make Protractor to work with Angular 5

Tags: angular, selenium, protractor, angular5, protractor-net

I want to run Protractor automation on Angular 5.
will it work? is it fully compatible? 
is there a place i can find some information  for protractor on angular 5?

---

edit: 
for example NgWebDriver uses ClientSideScripts which has hardcoded scripts with "angular." (e.g WaitForAngular) how it can be used with Angular 5?

Comment: Protractor is part of the angular project, written to specifically work with angular, so yes it will be fine: https://github.com/angular/protractor

Comment: You can see Angular-Cli, its a Command line tool which creates a project architecture with Protactor included: https://cli.angular.io/

Comment: for example NgWebDriver uses ClientSideScripts which has hardcoded scripts with "angular." (e.g WaitForAngular) how it can be used with Angular 5?